# Calc number of bits needed to represent a value using TMP

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I want to use template meta programming to calculate the minimum number of bits I need to represent a given number.  I've never used TMP before so that's probably what have is completely laughable.

```
struct ValueHolder
{
   typedef float value;
};

template<struct ValueHolder>
struct logB2
{
   enum { result = (((*(int*)&ValueHolder.value & 0x7f800000) >> 23) - 127) };
};

template <struct logB2 n>
struct bits2use {

    enum { return = !((n::return > 0) && !(n::return & (n::return-1))) ? n++ : n };
};

#ifndef NUM 
#define NUM 18 
#endif

int main()
{
   std::cout << bits2use<NUM>::return << '\n';
   return 0;
}
```

Here's what my run time code that I know works looks like:

```
int ch_bits;                    //how many bits needed to send the channel
float xf = CHN_CNT;             //need a float for log2 calc
int x = CHN_CNT;

//Calculate how many bits you need for a given integer, i.e. for a 64 channels you need
//6 bits to represent 0-63 unsigned.
ch_bits = ((*(int*)&xf & 0x7f800000) >> 23) - 127;  //log_2
if( !((x > 0) && !(x & (x-1))) )                    //true if x is not a power of 2
    ch_bits ++;
```

Comment: I count myself very experienced in C++, but `(*(int*)&(float)n & 0x7f800000)` scares me.  In fact, `&` on floats scares me.

Comment: Boost library has [Compile Time log2 Calculation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/integer/doc/html/boost_integer/log2.html).

Comment: Please fix these `template<struct ...>` !

Comment: @MooingDuck, haha, yea I realized it didn't even make sense what I had and changed it.  I know it's completely wrong but I'm hoping someone who knows how to do it will get what I'm trying to do.  The & on a float comes from some old code I found where it takes advantage of IEEE 32 bit to fast approximate log base 2

Comment: Additionally, `main` checks `bits2use<NUM>::return`.  `bits2use` does indeed have a `return` value, which depends recursively on `n::return`.  However, `n` is an int.  Nowhere in your code do you use or refer to `logB2`.  Additionally, `bits2use` is so complex, I cannot figure out what you intended it to do.

Comment: You cannot use a float value as a template parameter because a float's binary representation is not concrete enough. It might be rounded one way or another or have some other inaccuracy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you're looking for

```
#include <stdio.h>

template<int N> struct bits;
template<> struct bits<1> { enum { value=1 }; };
template<int N> struct bits { enum { value = 1 + bits<(N>>1)>::value }; };

int main() {
    printf("%i\n", bits<5000>::value);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried to make a more generic version, but I have an error somewhere.  Oh well.  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b51514de53d15a88

Comment: @MooingDuck: that's the joy of template metaprogramming. Hard to write, close to impossible to debug. And most of the time a totally pointless exercise in programming with artificially limited tools. Not much different from writing sudoku solvers in brainf**k.